# Is Data Driven Pages same as Map Books?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, data-driven-pages, map-book

Is there a difference between Data Driven Pages and Map Books in ArcMap 10.5 and, if so, did one replace the other?

Esri's web site is not clear about that which is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recollection is that Data Driven Pages were added to the ArcGIS Desktop core product at version 10.1 but it may have been 10.0.

Prior to that any map book and map series requirements for ArcGIS Desktop required installation of a free extension named DS Map Books or a paid extension named MPS Atlas which was originally part of the PLTS extension.

Since Data Driven Pages became part of ArcGIS Desktop core I think you can consider Data Driven Pages and Map Books to be synonymous.

If you move to ArcGIS Pro then map book and map series requirements are met using Map Series functionality, and Data Driven Pages no longer exists.

In the evolution from DS Map Books and MPS Atlas (I am not sure which came first) to Data Driven Pages and then to Map Series the concepts and base functionality have remained very similar.